# UICollectionView incorrectly hides cells whiles panning and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with a custom layout. The layout extends `UICollectionViewLayout`, not flow layout, and I override the following methods:

1. `collectionViewContentSize`
2. `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`
3. `prepareLayout`
4. `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`
5. `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`

The cells themselves are very large, each larger than the iPad's screen itself. When panning around the collection view, rarely a cell with disappear. It's very rare, so I've had to create a minimal example that always displays the problem, otherwise it can take minutes to manually reproduce with a fresh build.

The code below has hard-coded frames and transforms for each index path. The paths with the added rotation transform seem to show the issue easiest (though i've reproduced on cells w/o a rotation transform before as well). All cells have translations/scale transforms.

Importantly, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` always returns valid attributes that should be displayed, but the collection view seems to ignore the attributes sometimes and doesn't display the cell?

minimal example at: https://github.com/adamwulf/CollectionViewDisappearingCells

Is this a `UICollectionView` bug? Is this something else I'm overlooking? I've seen similar issues on stack overflow before, but they all seem to reference `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as opposed to entirely custom layouts. Their solution is to return the correct attributes from `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` which i'm already doing.

**Update:**
I've even tried returning *all* layout attributes from `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` since I only have ~20 objects. but returning everything all the time still doesn't solve the problem, so it's not an issue of the attributes not being returned when they should be.

**Update:**
It's looking more like a `UICollectionView` bug. If I adjust the `frame.origin.x` or `frame.size.width` of each item by adding as little as `0.0000000000001;`, then the cell no longer disappears.

The original frame of the item is `(280.39666002633368, -220.39666002633371, 595.71428571428578, 834)`. I can only assume there's some calculation within the UICollectionView that has a rounding error that this particular frame (or other unique frames) that triggers the error. If anyone has a proper solution/explanation for this bug, I'd love to hear it. In the meantime, I'll simply round the values of each `frame` to workaround the problem.

[image: Demo application showing the bug]